# Iphone Openears .dic file

Tags: iphone, openears

I want to create my own .dic file instead of cmu07a.dic provided by openears. Therefore I replaced all ARPA bets with my own in cmu07a.dic file. After changing cmu07a.dic, my app is crashing at lauching time.

here is error log: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range or index out of bounds'

Comment: It may be a good idea to expand on that question a little and provide some sample code. No one can guess what crashes your app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was Using Open ears default dictionary which was wrong selection. I made my own .dic file and then start pocketSphinxController with that static .dic file.
that solved my problem